# Firebase Storage Authentication not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm just trying to have the rules be that if the user is authenticated then they can write. When I try to upload an image to the gallery from the website I get back an error saying that I'm not authorized. I have authentication set up and working. Here are my rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my image upload code:

```
imgUploadHandler = () => {
        const image = this.props.imageUpload;
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/Gallery/${image.name}`).put(image);
        uploadTask.on('state_changed',
            (snapshot) => {
                // Progress function
                const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
                this.setState({ progress });
            }, 
            (error) => {
                // Error function
                console.log(error);
            }, 
            () => {
                // Complete function
                storage.ref('Gallery').child(image.name).getDownloadURL()
                .then(URL => {
                    const imageData = { imgURL: URL, name: image.name, width: "400"}
                    this.props.onImageUploaded(URL);
                    this.imgSelectedHandler(URL);
                    Axios.post(`/Gallery.json?auth=${this.props.token}`, imageData);
                })
            })
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that suggests a user is definitely signed in at the time it's being executed.

Comment: Can I send that info to Firebase storage somehow?

Comment: No, it's picked up automatically by the SDK.